# How to hide the input text after 5 milliseconds in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can someone help me with the toggle function, I have an input field for the secretid which
comes from API, now on click of eye button in the input field, secretid needs to be shown
for 5ms and id should automatically set to '******' after the timer.

```
 const HideID = "****************"; 

   togglePassword = () => {
const currentSecretID = this.state.secretID
  ? this.state.secretID
  : "********";
setTimeout(() => {
  this.setState({
    secretID: currentSecretID,
    showID: !this.state.showID,
  });
}, 10);
setTimeout(() => {
  this.setState({
    secretID: HideID,
  });
}, 100);
//clearInterval(50)
```

};

```
Input field looks like
         <Input placeholder={HideID} 
   value={showID ? secretID :  HideID}/>
             <InputGroupAddon
                     class="fa fa-fw fa-eye field_icon togglepassword"
                      addonType="append"
                    >
                      <InputGroupText>
                        <i
                          class="far fa-eye"
                          onClick={this.togglePassword}
                        ></i>
                      </InputGroupText>
                    </InputGroupAddon>
                  


  where am I doing wrong inside the function?
```

Comment: const HideID = "****************";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...needs to be shown for 5ms...

A couple of problems there:

1. The human eye generally can't handle something that brief. As I understand it, a really, really dialled-in alert person might be able to handle 30ms, but for an average person, 100ms is the lower limit. And even that is too little time to read anything.
2. If only 5ms have passed, you don't know that React has re-rendered the component (updated the DOM).
3. Even if React has updated the DOM, you don't even know if the browser has rendered it as painting the page typically only happens every 16.7ms or so (60 times per second).

To handle that, if you really want to do it this way, use a longer delay and hook into update and rendering; see comments:

```
// Handling the click, we just set the information to display
onEyeClick() {
    this.setState({
        secretID: currentSecretID,
        showID: !this.state.showID,
    });
}

// Watch for component updates
componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.state.showID && !this.waitingToHideID) {
        // The component updated to start showing the ID; wait to hide it and remember we're doing that
        this.waitingToHideID = true;
        requestAnimationFrame(() => {
            // The browser is *about* to update the display; wait 100ms after this
            // so the human can see it
            setTimeout(() => {
                // It's been 100ms, hide it again
                this.setState({
                    secretID: HideID, // *** Why? What makes state less secure thatn `currentSecretID`?
                    showID: false,
                });
                this.waitingToHideID = false;
            }, 100);
        });
    }
}
```

Live Example:

```js
let currentSecretID = "the secret";
const HideID = "*************";
class Example extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            secretID: HideID,
            showID: false,
        };
        this.onEyeClick = this.onEyeClick.bind(this);
    }

    // Handling the click, we just set the information to display
    onEyeClick() {
        this.setState({
            secretID: currentSecretID,
            showID: !this.state.showID,
        });
    }

    // Watch for component updates
    componentDidUpdate() {
        if (this.state.showID && !this.waitingToHideID) {
            // The component updated to start showing the ID; wait to hide it and remember we're doing that
            this.waitingToHideID = true;
            requestAnimationFrame(() => {
                // The browser is *about* to update the display; wait 100ms after this
                // so the human can see it
                setTimeout(() => {
                    // It's been 100ms, hide it again
                    this.setState({
                        secretID: HideID, // *** Why? What makes state less secure thatn `currentSecretID`?
                        showID: false,
                    });
                    this.waitingToHideID = false;
                }, 100);
            });
        }
    }

    render() {
        const {secretID, showID} = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                ID: {secretID}
                <div>
                    <input type="button" value="Eye" onClick={this.onEyeClick} disabled={showID} />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: To help echo TJ's narrative that 5ms isn't long enough, see [Reason for delays longer than specified](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#reasons_for_delays) which explains many browsers enforce a minimum delay, 4ms for most, so trying to invoke a callback in 5ms is very nearly the minimum it *can* be delayed. 100ms is a much better value and if you search around you'll find many libraries use transition/animation timings more in the 200-250ms range as these are more perceptible to the average human eye.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by other answer, React DOM typically requires some time to re-render and update data in DOM. I would suggest not to set timeout for only `5 milisecond`.

You can change `togglePassword` function like below to toggle your input to show secreId after 1000 miliseconds:

I assume you are storing your secred id which is returned by api in `secredId` state so we just need to toggle `showId` state

```
const togglePassword = () => {
  this.setState({
    showID: !this.state.showID,
  }, () => {
     setTimeout(() => {
       this.setState({
         showID: !this.state.showID,
       });
     }, 1000);
   });
};
```